# Can Zebra's SDK “Link-OS” be used to print to other thermal printers alongside Zebra's?

Tags: sdk, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I wanted to implement Zebra's SDK but I have to have the capability to print to other thermal printers besides Zebra's. Will Zebra's SDK have compatibility with other thermal printers that can connect to the server (such as a Star Micronics printer)?

Answer (score 1):

No - you would have to find a third party SDK to get support for both printers. Most SDK's these days have specific wording in the EULA that disallows use of an SDK with a competitive product. Apple would not want you using iOS libraries on an android device (not that they are compatible...).